# scroll to top button squarespace css

Tags: css, button, scroll, squarespace

Hi I would like to have a scroll to top button that scrolls with the page as you go down.

On the right side and mid way down the page.

Round and with a simple arrow pointing up ^

Thanks for your help in advance!

KIM[screen shot of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s00UX.png)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you!

[How TO - Scroll Back To Top Button](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_to_top.asp)